# Restriction of the sheaf of relative differentials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, fibration, cotangent-bundles, pullback

Let $f:X\rightarrow C$ be a morphism, where $C$ is a smooth curve, and let $\Omega_f$ be the sheaf of relative differentials.

For $t\in C$ let $i_t:X_t = f^{-1}(t)\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion of the fiber of $f$ over $t$. Does there exist an isomorphism $i_t^{*}\Omega_f \cong \Omega_{X_t}$ ?

Comment: Yes. This EGA IV, 16.4.5 (there might exist a lighter reference). Note that this has not much to do with the dualizing sheaf.

Comment: Hartshorne Proposition II.8.10.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you!